# firefox url bar handler

Tags: firefox, url-rewriting, firefox-addon

I have an idea about a plugin to write for firefox, but have no idea where to start, so any comments would be welcome. I have a few sites that I need to query several times per day using a certain ID. I'd like to be able to type in the url bar some sort of identifier followed by dash followed by the **id** (e.g fid-123) I'm trying to query and make firefox do something in the background and finally redirect me to the correct URL with the respective .

I've been toying around with greasemonkey but doesn't seem to fit the purpose. Has anyone done anything similar or knows how to go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a bookmark with `%s` in the querystring and `fid` as the keyword, then type `fid 123` in the address bar.

Comment: No programming necessary! Good call.